# WYSIWYG Geometry Tool

Tags: data-visualization, math, wysiwyg

I need a tool that is able to:

- Draw 2D/3D geometric objects given the sufficient attributes (center, raduis for a circle, lower-left corner and side length for a cube etc.)
- Show the intersection points of those objects.
- Show the distance between some specific points (like intersections, centers, a point on a surface to another point etc.)
- Let me modify the objects by drag&drop, wihout closing the initial window.

gnuplot is the best alternative so far, but it requires a spaghetti code for a little bit complicated cases.

Edit: I found [Dr. Geo](http://www.drgeo.eu/) but it is not so useful and user friendly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/):

- Free (+ [portable version available](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/portable))
- Works with Windows/Mac/Linux (even Android/iPhone/Windows Phone as well as in Google Chrome)
- has some [Measurement Tools](http://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Measurement_Tools)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you. But there are two different versions: one is on the website and other is in repository. Which one should I install?

Comment: Glad it works for you. What repository?

Comment: Ubuntu repository. Sorry, I forgot to mention the OS :)

Comment: I'd go with the repo, just make sure the version you get is the latest one, i.e. GeoGebra 4.4!

Comment: +1 for GeoGebra. I really like to use it both privately and to show things in class. I downloaded it from the website to make sure I got the latest version.